# Adding marker at dynamic location on WMS map with GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wms, sld, cql

I need to generate a static map image with a marker at coordinates specified in the WMS request URL.

I have a GeoServer instance which provides the WMS layer, and I am able to get static map images out of it. Now I am looking to do something like:

https://map.example.com/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/png&LAYERS=mylayer&CRS=EPSG:3067&BGCOLOR=0xffffff&WIDTH=1024&HEIGHT=1024&BBOX=459649.353,6872438.069,460359.740,6873265.169&**something-something-marker-at-pos=460004.547,6872851.619**

which would return a map image of the given bounding box, with a marker drawn at the given position.

I assume the marker appearance would be specified with GeoServer SLD, but what would be the glue between the style and *something-something*-part above? CQL?

Is this possible with GeoServer alone? If yes - how, and is it also possible to add several markers per request?

To clarify:

- The marker location is not stored anywhere (PostGIS etc), but is
  provided along with the WMS request.
- I can not use any JavaScript
  libraries for drawing on top of the map, as the images needs to be
  static PNG/GIF.
- Unfortunately I cannot provide an example link to
  the WMS service as it requires authentication.

Comment: Your client could generate a custom SLD and pass it with an SLD=path/to/custom/sld& parameter

Comment: You can provide an inline feature in your SLD https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/layers.html#inlinefeature which could contain environment variables

Comment: @nmtoken I'm not sure how this would help or how to do this, can you provide a concrete example & answer?

Comment: @IanTurton Can you elaborate on how to do this? Why would I want to use environment variables?

Comment: You could use a single SLD and pass in the coordinates as environment variables to save creating a new SLD each time if that was easier. I think there's an example somewhere in the docs but I can't find it on my phone

Comment: How do the coordinates from the WMS request URL get into environment variables?